# How to start MySql using ANT task

Tags: mysql, ant

I need to start and stop mysql 5.5 using ant task.

The earlier ANT script was doing it for hsqldb database for which the class it was using was `org.hsqldb.Server`. Could someone tell me which class to use for mysql 5.5.

Following was being use in case of hsqldb for mydb:
        `<java fork="true"  spawn="true" classname="org.hsqldb.Server" classpathref="build.runtime.classpath">
            <arg  line="-database.0 file:data/mydb -dbname.0 mydb"/>
        </java>`

I need to have the eqivalant for mysql 5.5. I know a connector is used to connect to mysql 5.5 database, I use `mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar`.

Could someone just tell me how to start and stop mysql database using an ant script.

Thanks.

Comment: hsqldb is designed as an embedded database. Mysql on the other hand is a client-server based application. The server component would normally be installed and running as an OS service. Perhaps give some more background on why you're trying to do this first?

Comment: @Mark: I already have mysql 5.5 installed. I am using an application that has `start-db` a task that runs before the server starts. But that application is using hsqldb. What I want to do is use mysql as the database for that application. So I just wanted to use the same script that is already there and connect to already running database when the `start-db` runs.

Comment: And my point is that if you have mysql installed, it's highly likely that it's already running in the background. hsqldb is a special case, it's designed as database to be embedded (and executed) within your application.

Comment: @Mark: So is it not possible to start and stop mysql somehow from ant script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more normal to configure MySQL to [automatically start](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/automatic-start.html)  when the machine boots. MySQL is designed to run continually in the background.

If you really want to stop and start MySQL from within ANT it's possible to invoke the server scripts (Assuming of course MySQL is running on the same machine as the build).

```
<target name="start-db">
  <exec executable="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" osfamily="windows">
  </exec>

  <exec executable="mysql.server" osfamily="unix">
    <arg value="start"/>
  </exec>
</target>

<target name="stop-db">
  <exec executable="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" osfamily="windows">
    <arg value="-u"/>
    <arg value="root"/>
    <arg value="shutdown"/>
  </exec>

  <exec executable="mysql.server" osfamily="unix">
    <arg value="stop"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

**Note:**

- This script contains commands to start/stop on both windows and unix.
- The MySQL documentation describes [how to start Mysql from the windows command line](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/windows-start-command-line.html)

Comment: Could you please tell me how to connect to a particular database (ex. mydb) using ant script as well. Thanks a heap.

Comment: @skip Connect? You mean how to use the ANT SQL task, or do you want infromation on how to configure the mysql jdbc URL? I'd suggest posting a new question with more details of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I looked at http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sql.html and what I understand from it is `<sql 
            driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"
            userid="root"
            password="password">
        </sql>` should suffice to connect to `mydb`. It I am correct then could please just tell me where should I place it in the above `star-db` task you posted above as the answer. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @skip Still don't understand what you're trying to do.... Yes the details you've supplied above are sufficient to run SQL statements, using the ANT SQL task.

Comment: I am actually not sure about how should I try it. Should I try it like `<target name="start-db"> <exec executable="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" osfamily="windows"> </exec> <sql driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/broadleaf" userid="root" password="password"> </sql> </target>`? That is <sql>..</sql> after `<exec>..</exec>` inside `<target>`. I worked with ANT ages ago and that too only for a very little while so just wanted make sure how should I exactly try it before I scratching my head again :(