# How to connect to a database created in using ANT

Tags: mysql, ant

I need to connect to "mydb" database created in MySQL 5.5.

I figured out from http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sql.html that following should do the job, but ti does not.

```
<sql
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/broadleaf"
    userid="root"
    password="password">
</sql>
```

Then in [the other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653379/how-to-start-mysql-using-ant-task/10657485#10657485) that following could be used to start and stop MySQL using ANT:

```
<target name="start-db">
  <exec executable="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" osfamily="windows">
  </exec>

  <exec executable="mysql.server" osfamily="unix">
    <arg value="start"/>
  </exec>
</target>

<target name="stop-db">
  <exec executable="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" osfamily="windows">
    <arg value="-u"/>
    <arg value="root"/>
    <arg value="shutdown"/>
  </exec>

  <exec executable="mysql.server" osfamily="unix">
    <arg value="stop"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

Could someone tell me how to glue both these scripts together to start MySQL database and then connect to a particular database (ex. mydb) using an ANT script? And similarly  stop the database and disconnect from that database (mysql).

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the error messages you're getting when you try these targets ?  They look OK to me.

Comment: @gareth_bowles: I haven't actually tried them together yet. I am not sure about how should I try them. Should I put inside `<target name="start-db">
  <exec executable="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" osfamily="windows">
  </exec>

<sql
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/broadleaf"
    userid="root"
    password="password">
</sql>
</target>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking how to tie everything together in a complete ANT script?

```
<project name="database-stuff" default="make-it-so">

    <target name="make-it-so" depends="start-db,run-sql,stop-db"/>

    <target name="start-db">
      <exec executable="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" osfamily="windows">
      </exec>

      <exec executable="mysql.server" osfamily="unix">
        <arg value="start"/>
      </exec>
    </target>

    <target name="stop-db">
      <exec executable="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" osfamily="windows">
        <arg value="-u"/>
        <arg value="root"/>
        <arg value="shutdown"/>
      </exec>

      <exec executable="mysql.server" osfamily="unix">
        <arg value="stop"/>
      </exec>
    </target>

    <target name="run-sql">
       <sql driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/broadleaf"
            userid="root"
            password="password">

           -- SQL STATEMENTS GO HERE!!
       </sql>
    </target>

</project>
```

If not you'll have to provide more details of the kind of error you're experiencing.

Comment: This was exactly I was asking for. Many thanks. I will let you know in case I get an error while running the script above. Thanks again :).